# connect to a site to site vpn using software only?

Tags: vpn, site-to-site-vpn

My company needs remote access to an application on another company's network.  The other company is giving us site-to-site vpn access.

The other company does not need access to our network, and only one computer from our network will be accessing their network.  Ideally we would use regular regular remote-access vpn, however that is not an option due to politics.

Can I get this set up on our end without doing any hardware-level configuration? I mean, is there some software that will let me set up a site-to-site vpn from our one computer to their network and make it look like a site-to-site from the other company's end?

edit: the other company is using a cisco router, in case that is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) will let you do a direct computer-to-computer VPN. May that work for your situation? The remote end computer could be a windows terminal server or linux ssh gateway, thereby giving you more or less full access to whatever parts of their network that host has access to.

--Edit--
It is somewhat unclear what you're asking for here. Company A needs access to Company B's network. Company B has agreed to grant this access, but due to politics within Company A, you are unable to get things set up properly. Is that a fair analysis of the situation? If Company B is as large and important as you communicated in your comment below, you'd think that Company A would do what it takes to get around whatever "politics" are preventing this arrangement from working out.

You haven't given any details of the configuration, but I'd guess the other company has set up an IPSec VPN for you. Technically speaking, there isn't a whole lot of difference between a "remote user" VPN setup and a site-to-site VPN aside from some ACLs and routing rules. If you have information about how the other end of the VPN connection is set up, you should be able to use an IPSec client within your network to gain access.

Comment: unfortunately that would not work in our situation. the other company is a large and important client, but they are not open to suggestions. however we do use hamachi on other projects :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's all possible but depends on the type of VPN.

You can create an IPSEC or PPTP VPN in windows through the network connections

Create new network connection in windows.
Select the option that says you're connecting into a network at my workplace then click next.
Select the option that you're using a Virtual Private Network.  etc.

If it's OpenVPN then you can download and install the client OpenVPN onto windows.  This is also very easy to use.

In any case, you'll need to get the VPN details from the other company.